# Why is accuracy lower 0.01, but prediction very good (99,99%)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, loss

I did my first own neural network with TensorFlow 2 in Python.
My idea was to build a neural network which is able to find the solution to translate binary numbers (8-bit) in decimal numbers.
After a few tries: Yeah it works very precise!

But what I don't understand: The accuracy is very low.

Second thing is: The model has to train over 200.000 values!
For 256 possible answers. Where are the failure in my code/model?

```
#dataset
def dataset(length, num):
 global testdata, solution
 testdata = np.random.randint(2, size=(num, length))

 solution = testdata.copy()
 solution = np.zeros((num, 1))

 for i in range(num):
  for n in range(length):
   x = testdata [i,length - n -1] * (2 ** n)
   solution [i] += x

length = 8
num = 220000
dataset (length, num)

#Modell
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_squared_error',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#Training und Evaluate
model.fit(testdata, solution, epochs=4)
model.evaluate(t_testdata,  t_solution, verbose=2)
model.summary()
```

loss: 6.6441e-05 - accuracy: 0.0077

Shouldn't it be like 0.77 or higher?

Comment: Accuracy is a a meaningless metric for regression. as long as you are even 1 unit of machine precision off, the prediction does not match the label. Hence it is counted as a zero for the average odds of CLASSIFYING right. It doesn't mean it is a bad prediction per se.

Comment: You probably need `activation='sigmoid'` if you want to use accuracy metrics

Answer (score 0):

You should not consider accuracy as metrics for the regression problem, since you are trying to output a single value, even if the small changes in the precision it will result as zero, you can consider below example.

Consider you are trying to predict value 15, and the model returns value 14.99, the resulting accuracy will still be zero.

```
m = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
_ = m.update_state([[15]], [[14.99]])
m.result().numpy()
```

Result:

```
0.0
```

You can consider the below list of metrics for regression.

- Regression metrics
- MeanSquaredError class
- RootMeanSquaredError class
- MeanAbsoluteError class
- MeanAbsolutePercentageError class
- MeanSquaredLogarithmicError class
- CosineSimilarity class
- LogCoshError class

I have tried the same problem with one of the above listed metrics and below is the result.

```
def bin2int(bin_list):
    #bin_list = [0, 0, 0, 1]
    int_val = ""
    for k in bin_list:
        int_val += str(int(k))
    #int_val = 11011011    
    return int(int_val, 2) 

def dataset(num):
    # num - no of samples
    bin_len = 8
    X = np.zeros((num, bin_len))
    Y = np.zeros((num))

    for i in range(num):
        X[i] = np.around(np.random.rand(bin_len)).astype(int)
        Y[i] = bin2int(X[i])
    return X, Y  


no_of_smaples = 220000
trainX, trainY = dataset(no_of_smaples)
testX, testY = dataset(5) 


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='mean_absolute_error',
              metrics=['mse']) 

model.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_data = (testX,testY),epochs=4) 
model.summary()
```

**Output:**

```
Epoch 1/4
6875/6875 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 27.6938 - mse: 2819.9429 - val_loss: 0.0066 - val_mse: 5.2560e-05
Epoch 2/4
6875/6875 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0580 - mse: 0.1919 - val_loss: 0.0066 - val_mse: 6.0013e-05
Epoch 3/4
6875/6875 [==============================] - 16s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0376 - mse: 0.0868 - val_loss: 0.0106 - val_mse: 1.2932e-04
Epoch 4/4
6875/6875 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0317 - mse: 0.0466 - val_loss: 0.0177 - val_mse: 3.2429e-04
Model: "sequential_11"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_24 (Dense)             multiple                  72        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_25 (Dense)             multiple                  9         
_________________________________________________________________
round_4 (Round)              multiple                  0         
=================================================================
Total params: 81
Trainable params: 81
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Predict:**

```
model.predict([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.]])
```

> array([[5.993815]], dtype=float32)